# Отрицательные индексы в первичном ключе

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Появился следующий вопрос в плане работы с PostgreSQL через Entity Framework.

Имеется следующая таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE "TankContentStateHistory" (
"TankContentStateHistoryId" integer NOT NULL SET DEFAULT nextval('"TankContentStateHistory_TankContentStateHistoryId_seq"'::regclass),
"AverageTemperature" double precision NOT NULL,
...
"GTVolume" double precision DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL);
```

TankContentStateHistoryId берет свои значения из перечисления TankContentStateHistory_TankContentStateHistoryId_seq:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "TankContentStateHistory_TankContentStateHistoryId_seq"
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NO MINVALUE
NO MAXVALUE
CACHE 1;
```

Значения должны быть все время положительными, но в последнее время стали появляться моменты, когда первичный ключ становится с отрицательным значением и откуда оно берется - не понятно.
Логи PostgreSQL ясности не вносят:

```
2021-09-19 00:45:58 MSK ОШИБКА:  повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "PK_TankContentStateHistory"
2021-09-19 00:45:58 MSK ПОДРОБНОСТИ:  Ключ "("TankContentStateHistoryId")=(-2147482602)" уже существует.
2021-09-19 00:45:58 MSK ОПЕРАТОР:  INSERT INTO "TankContentStateHistory" ("TankContentStateHistoryId", ... "GTVolume")
VALUES ($1, ..)
```

EntityFrameworkCore по сути дублирует тоже самое:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> Npgsql.PostgresException: 23505: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "PK_TankContentStateHistory"
в Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
```

Вопрос в следующем - в каком месте может возникнуть проблема? Потому что после тщетных попыток уставить значение, все следующие значения ключа идет дальше по последовательности (например, id = 2044, потом отрицательное значение id=-454635, после id=2045).

Comment: Отрицательные значения - это временные ключи. При вставке записей в БД они будут заменены на настоящие.

Comment: Отрицательные значения именно в таблице БД появляются? Или просто в сушности наличествуют до вставки методом SaveChanges?

Comment: Александр, значения именно в таблице отрицательные. Хотя возможно вы правы в том, что отрицательные значения прилетают именно из сущности.